How to fix nodejs express app when deployed always gives error 400 bad request
When Im running my express app on localhost the result is always status 200 success but when deployed it always give me status 400 bad request. this happens on /getToken endpoint let r7 = await axios.post request.
here is my full code.
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

function genChars(length) {
    let randomChars = '';
    const characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength);
        randomChars += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return randomChars;
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("This API was made by HackMeSenpai.")
})

app.get('/getToken', async function(req, res) {
    try {
        let {data} = await axios.get('https://chatgateai.onrender.com/getToken')
        let r7 = await axios.post('https://chatgate.ai/wp-json/firebase/v2/users/register-autologin',{
            'user': {
                'userId': data.data.users[0].localId,
                'password': genChars(10),
                'email': data.data.users[0].email,
                'providers': [
                    data.data.users[0].providerUserInfo[0].providerId
                ]
            }
        }, {
            headers: {
                'auth-source': 'wordpress',
                'cookie': data.cookie,
                'firebase-login-key': data.firebaseKey,
                'origin': 'https://chatgate.ai',
                'referer': 'https://chatgate.ai/login?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fchatgate.ai%2F&lang=en',
                'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; vivo 1811) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.40 Mobile Safari/537.36',
            }
        });
        let wp_login_cookie = r7.headers['set-cookie'][r7.headers['set-cookie'].length - 1].split(';')[0] + ';sbjs_session=pgs=1|||cpg=https://chatgate.ai/'
        res.send({
            session_token: btoa(data.cookie + wp_login_cookie)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (!e.response)
            res.send({
                error: e.message
            });
        else {
            res.send({
                error: `${e.response.status} ${e.response.statusText}`,
                data: e.response.data.message
            })
        }
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`)
})

the response data on localhost on /getToken
{session_token:"A-VERY-LONG-TOKEN"}
the response data on /getToken when deployed
response when deployed

Hi! I suspect you may need to inspect what the data returned from https://chatgateai.onrender.com/getToken is when you're in the localhost mode, as it seems to be the only possible difference when you make the POST later.
